# Trying to create a custom primary key in a SQL Database, need advice

Tags: java, sql, database, string, key

So my group is trying to find a way to generate a unique primary key for our crew table. But we don't want it to be integer based, we want it to be string based. Are we doing it right?

```
public String crewMemberPrimaryKeyGenerator(int ID){
     String newPrimaryKey = "8";fdasdf
     for (int i = 0; i<ID; i++){
           newPrimaryKey.concat("=");
     }
     newPrimaryKey.concat("D");
     return newPrimaryKey;
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there, which is probably why people are downvoting this question.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you let the database generate this for you as a GUID. In SQL use a call to newid(), or if you're in MySQL you would use UUID().

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use GUID which generates to be based on String.
2. Continue using int, but combine this int with a suffix, for example: N1,N2